# Capybara Poltergeist - Site shows message to enable cookies

Tags: capybara, headless-browser, poltergeist

I am running Capybara 1.1.2 with Poltergeist 1.0.1 for headless testing. The test runs fine with selenium driver. However with poltergeist, the site snapshot states that cookies are disabled. Am I missing any config. Shouldn't cookies be enabled by default?

Answer (score 1):

You can make sure that the cookies are enabled in Capybara before setting the session.

```
    Capybara.register_driver :my_firefox_driver do |app|
      Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, {:js_errors => false, 
                             :cookies => true, :window_size => [1280, 1024]})
    end
    self.session = Capybara::Session.new(:my_firefox_driver)
```

Comment: That's not the correct answer in the context my question was. Cookies are already enabled.